# PHP cURL Post Failing or no Data returning where did I go wrong?

Tags: php, soap, curl

Heres my bit o' php, tryin to figure out why I'm not getting a `$result` going to the URL it produces will give me a valid JSON result based on a get or post. So I think my problem is how I am using cURL. So I need someone take on this.

```
        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();
        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($params));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);           
                    if(!$result)
                    {
                        $error = curl_error($ch); echo $error; return false;
                    }
        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        //return json_decode($result);
                    echo $result;
```

***EDITED CODE ABOVE From original Post***

`$error` does not report anything. I changed the return json... to echo to see if that was doing anything and it printed out '**Disallowed Key Characters.**' on the screen.

***EDIT 2***

```
$url = http://domain.com/search
$params = array('q'=>'search,term')
```

`$params` is put through a foreach loop which builds the `$fields_string`

```
$fields_string = '?';
foreach($params as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$fields_string = substr($fields_string,0,-1);
```

fields_string looks like `?ll=37.2790669,-121.874722&range=10` in the end (for what I am doing currently, I have anywhere from 1-12 optional parameters that can be passed which is why I am building it the way I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding error checking to make sure `curl_exec` is executing successfully and to get a meaningful error message back on the server.

something like:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    //Make string url safe with urlencode
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,urlencode($url));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($params));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if(!$result) {
        $error = curl_error();
        //$error now contains the error thrown when curl_exec failed to execute
        //echo this to terminal or to an error box in the browser?
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result);
```

Post your resulting error here if you still need help.
Also, here are the manual pages for the two functions I took advantage of:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

-Cheers

Comment: Updated my post, after giving it a shot, found that it is making it to return result, however echoing out the result gives me `Disallowed Key Characters.`

Comment: Can you update your post to include the values of `$url` `$fields_string` and the `$params` values as well? I believe the problem lies with the characters in `$url` not being properly escaped

Comment: updated again, cant be specific with the actual domain right now though as it resides behind a VPN and I am not allowed to share it unfortunately.

Comment: Alright, not knowing the URL may be problematic but we should be able to rule it out with a little test. I added it to the source code above.

Comment: The Disallowed error went away then, 'Couldn't resolve host 'http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fsearch'`

Comment: here is an example of the JSON output from the same URL gone to manually in the browser. Which again accepts post/get. And is output with JSON headers. `{"status":"success","msg":{"ps":[31,1,2],"members":[{"id":"3063","name":null,"pix":"unknown","distance":"1.63 mi."},{"id":"1553","name":"Sabrina Randle","pix":"sabrina_randle.png","distance":"2.67 mi."}`

Comment: figured it out to some extent, apparently the `$fields_string = '?'` was throwing it all off, i took the ? out and left it as a blank string to append to and it worked like a charm. However I ran into another problem now, that being my "logged" in session seems to fail is there a way to pass the session info with a curl request?

Answer (score 1):

```
//set POST variables
$url = "http://example.com/edsym/registration.php"; // URL to calc.cgi
$fields = array(
'namee'=>urlencode($name),
'city'=>urlencode($city),
'phh'=>urlencode($ph),
'emaill'=>urlencode($email),
'msg1'=>urlencode("Message type")
                );
$fields_string=" ";
//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

I am using curl to post like this and its working